# Sort item by value mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sort a collection by putting items with a specific values before other items.

For example I want all the items with `"getthisfirst": "yes"` to be before all the others.

```
{"getthisfirst": "yes"}
{"getthisfirst": "yes"}
{"getthisfirst": "no"}
{"getthisfirst": "maybe"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This as a general concept is called "weighting". So without any other mechanism in place, then you handle this logically in a MongoDB query by "projecting" the values for the "weight" into the document logically.

Your method for "projecting" and altering the fields present in your document is the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, and specifically it's [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) pipeline stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "getthisfirst": 1,
        "weight": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$getthisfirst", "yes" ] },
                10,
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$getthisfirst", "maybe" ] },
                    5,
                    0
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "weight": -1 } }
]);
```

The [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator here is a ["ternary"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) ( if/then/else ) condition where the first argument is a conditional statment arriving to boolean `true|false`. If `true` "then" the second argument is returned as the result, otherwise the "else" or third argument is returned in response.

In this "nested" case, then where the "yes" is a match then a certain "weight" score is assigned, otherwise we move on to the next condition test where when "maybe" is a match then anoter score is assigned, or otherwise the score is `0` since we only have three posibilities to match.

Then the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) condition is applied in order to, well "order" ( in decending order ) the results with the largest "weight" on top.