# Sort a mongo collection by a string field

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I am working on a Meteor project and I would like to sort a Mongo collection by a text field. This is an example of the collection.

```
{ _id: 1,
  status: 'liked',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 08 2016 18:15:13 GMT+0200 (CEST),
},
{ _id: 2,
  status: 'sent',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 06 2016 12:12:13 GMT+0200 (CEST),
},
{ _id: 3,
  status: 'accepted',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 07 2016 18:32:13 GMT+0200 (CEST),
},
{ _id: 4,
  status: 'rejected',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 07 2016 18:42:17 GMT+0200 (CEST),
},
{ _id: 5,
  status: 'confirmed',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 07 2016 18:52:17 GMT+0200 (CEST),
},
{ _id: 6,
  status: 'declined',
  updatedAt: Wed Sep 07 2016 18:19:37 GMT+0200 (CEST),
}
```

Is there a way of sorting the collection using the status field?.

In particular, I would like to sort it this way:
1. confirmed 2. accepted 3. sent 4. liked 5. declined 6. rejected

Does something like this exists?

```
UserInternship.find({
    "applicant._id": Meteor.userId(),
  },
  {
    sort: {
      status: {'confirmed', 'accepted', 'sent', 'liked', 'declined', 'rejected'},
    },
  }).fetch()
```

Comment: [How about this?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bmongodb%5d%20weighting)

Comment: @Styvane gave a nice search, a similar question with nice answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896241/sort-item-by-value-mongodb/31896496#31896496)

Comment: I know there are plugins that allow aggregates in Meteor, but I don't think it supports them out-of-the-box (at least, it didn't in the past). So, if you don't want to add a plugin for aggregates, you could simply store a numeric value in a separate field and sort on that.  Basically, store the values twice: Once with the "human readable" value and again with a numeric value representing the weight/enumeration.  Only issue there is you have to maintain the value twice.

Comment: On the client, you should be able to provide a function as the `sort` clause.